# Install RavenDB Bundles on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor, ravenhq

To extend RavenDB's capabilities I would like to install the [bundles](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles) that are available out of the box. This is easy on a local installation, but how is this done when the database is hosted by AppHarbor and RavenHQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [RavenHQ docs](https://ravenhq.zendesk.com/entries/21336716-what-ravendb-bundles-are-supported), you can have bundles added to your database by writing them.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that page. I will write them and hope they can add it :)